# How to scroll vertically & programmatically a textbox on a form with Visual Studio 2010 express with Vbasic

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am using Visual Studio Express 2010 with visual basic.  I am trying to both learn and test the product enough in 30 days to see if the regular Visual Studio 2010 (Vbasic in particular) will meet my needs.   Here's the problem/question.  I have an output kind of textbox on a form, textbox1, which is written to programmatically.  I have set it to be multiline, enabled, read only, and scrollbar: vertical.  I need to fix it so that the scroll thumb moves to the bottom automatically each time the text is overwritten or appended to.  (I am overwriting, but actually adding to the textbox (TextBox1.Text & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & newtextdata).  The values properties of TextBox1 includes a minimum which is zero and a maximum which is 100.  Changing those doesn't seem to help.  There is no autoscroll property on a textbox.  I even tried setting the textbox to scrollbars: none and then adding from the toolbar a VScrollBar, but I couldn't get it to hook up to TextBox1 and I don't know how to make that one scroll programmatically to the bottom either.  Would you please give me the necessary code?  Also, if there needs to be a system import, would you please mention that too?  This is a make or break feature for me.  If this product and vbasic won't do this, then I have to look at something else.  I have searched already through three books plus online here and can't figure it out.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestion here (from David), I came up with something that works, and because it wasn’t exactly the same as David’s suggestion, I wanted to share the specifics with you…

First, I added a public sub…

PublicClassForm1
PublicSub ScrollToCaret()

EndSub

Then in an Accept button routine for the user‘s input, I did the following….

```
        OutputTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
        OutputTextBox.SelectedText = strTextBeingAdded + _
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbCrLf
```

I had a problem, though with the OutputTextBox.Text set on the Design page and had to erase it and put it into the Form load event so that it would scroll to caret there too...

PrivateSub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) HandlesMyBase.Load
        OutputTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
        OutputTextBox.SelectedText = "Initial Description” & strWrap + _
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbCrLf

Thanks for the comment that led me to this!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) property:

```
TextBox.SelectionStart = Len(TextBox.Text)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and couldn't get it to work for some reason, perhaps because I had some setting which disagreed with it??  But I thank you profusely for your comment, because it led me to related areas, and now my problem is resolved!  I will share my solution here...

Comment: David, it seems I have violated some etiquette here by answering your answer and by giving the solution I found due to your answer.  Please know that I meant no offense--I am very new here.  If you wish you can share the info I sent you.  If you will send me your e-mail to Timevessel@aol.com I will send my apology more privately and ask how you want me to handle this.  Thank you so much for your kindness in responding to me.  I realize I am answering an answer again, but I knew no other way of getting in touch with you.

Comment: @Timevessel - no worries. However, if you do manage to solve your problem yourself, the way to indicate it is to add your own answer (rather than comment on someone else's), and mark your own answer as the accepted answer. Thanks!